# LET Function in Excel I'm using is not valid as per the system

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was just using the LET function when I use the ENTER button, it stated that *the first argument of let must be a valid name.* How can I fix this?

[image: LET]

I tried this formula:

```
=LET(FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,LEFT($S$6:$EH$6,4)="Tran"),FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,$S$6:$EH$6="Amount"),SUM($S7:$EH7>=$EP$4)*($S7:$EH7<=$EQ$4)*FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,$S$6:$EH$6="Amount")))
```

Comment: Wrong syntax. You must assign a variable inside `LET()` function.

Comment: Can you show me how it's done? I just want to know what variable I needed to put. I want to add up all the amount from S7 to EH7 which will be based from dates (EQ4 & EP4).

Answer (score 0):

LET(): the [MS example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=To%20use%20the%20LET%20function,LET%20supports%20up%20to%20126.) is pretty clear:

```
=LET(x, 1, y, 1, x+y)
```

This produces 2. Put in a variable name, then the value of that variable. Keep adding pairs until you've done all those. Append your calculation as the last argument.

For the formula you posted ...

```
=LET(FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,LEFT($S$6:$EH$6,4)="Tran"),FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,$S$6:$EH$6="Amount"),SUM($S7:$EH7>=$EP$4)*($S7:$EH7<=$EQ$4)*FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,$S$6:$EH$6="Amount")))
```

... you are missing variable names. Use LET() to make your final calculation more readable, as:

```
=LET(amount, FILTER($S$7:$EH$7,$S$6:$EH$6="Amount"),
SUM($S7:$EH7>=$EP$4)*($S7:$EH7<=$EQ$4)*amount))
```

Without sample data, I'm not certain this formula will actually do what you want it to do, however!